# Is there a PHP equivalient to Hibernate Validator?

Tags: php, validation

Hibernate Validator allows you to annotate properties with validation rules:

http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html

Is there a PHP equivalent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Symfony Validator with Doctrine
[Symfony2 and Doctrine2 Validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545561/unique-constraints-in-doctrine-2-symfony-2)

Maybe you should check [Validation of Entites](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/cookbook/validation-of-entities.html) on Doctrine2.

Comment: Now I am more confused. Doctrine says it has no validators. Does that mean I need to use Symfony2?

Comment: Yes, using Validator Service http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html. Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545561/unique-constraints-in-doctrine-2-symfony-2

Comment: can I use that without the rest of the Symfony framework? I've heard good things, but am using another framework (though am switching to Doctrine)

Comment: No symfony framework, is a component of symfony https://github.com/symfony/Validator

Comment: but can i use Validator somewhat independently, or does it have lots of dependencies on Symfony? thx

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with hibernate validators but have a look at [PHP's filters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.php) (in particular the "validate filters" section).

If you want a more complex/complete solution at the cost of not being part of the php core itself I've found the [Zend_Validate component of the Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.validate.introduction.html) great to work with (you do not need to use the Zend Framework for the rest of your project, you can use only this specific component by itself).

Comment: I don't see how those decorate properties and generate the validation code for me...looks like a lot of manual work. thanks