# Doctrine2, uniqueConstraint on JoinColumn for ZF2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, unique-constraint

I have a data feed that has duplicated content (no idea why, it's an external feed), however we need to insert all items with a constraint on the title and type, i.e.

These can exist:

- Name_A, Type_A
- Name_A, Type_B

But only one of these should exist:

- Name_A, Type_A
- Name_A, Type_A

Here's the Entity code I'm using:

```
/**
 * Restauration
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="restauration", uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_unique", columns={"name_1", "restauration_type"})})
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="iMotionTools\Repository\RestaurationRepository")
 */
class Restauration
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name_1", type="string", length=128, nullable=true)
     */
    private $name1;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="RestaurationType", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="restauration_type", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $type;
}
```

But I get this error when parsing and inserting the data:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 columns name_1, restauration_type are not unique:91:C:\coding\currate\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php
```

I'm wondering whether the easy way is to just ignore the thrown exception? Looks like it's a `driverExceptionDuringQuery` that gets thrown during my call to `$em->persist();` but I'm not sure how I would ignore if the call contains the above error?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore that, stop using constraint integrity.

> {@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="name_unique", columns={"name_1" //etc...

Your data has name_1 not unique this is why you have this error, integrity constraint check this, you can't ignore that, without remove the unique constraint parameters.

Edit :

You have to then, before persist data, check with your actual data in the table, if there is a duplicate entry for both name_1 AND Type, and do not persist them.

for check both you can use :

```
@UniqueEntity({"name", "type"})
```

found here :
[validation multiple constraint columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545561/unique-constraints-in-doctrine-2-symfony-2)

Even if it's for SF2, it's the same concept

Comment: I cannot use name_1 as unique since we have to have duplicates of name_1 with different "type"s... Ideally I want to catch the error and ignore only if it's for this duplicate 19 error (throw otherwise), or have the generated SQL come up with something like INSERT OR IGNORE INTO ? but not sure if that exists for sqlite?

Comment: The UniqueConstraint is there specifically so that we don't get duplicates of the same name + type (i.e. NameA, TypeA twice. but we accept NameA and different TypesA,B,C etc.)

Comment: check the data before persist them maybe.. and don't persist them if there is duplicate

Answer (score 0):

I've removed the UniqueConstraint attribute from the table and added a function to check the objects list (which later get `$entity->persist()`-ed), using an array so that I can easily use it for different entity types, and it seems to work well now.

```
        $key = $hashList ? '' : $page['id'];
        foreach ($hashList as $method) {
            $val = $object->{$method}();

            if(is_object($val)) {
                $val = $val->getId();
            }

            $key .= $val;
        }

        $key = md5($key);

        $objects[$key] = $object;
```

Where `$hashList = array('getName', 'getType')` - and getType returns an object (since it's another entity), but which always has the getId() function... probably not the best solution but it works for my situation...