# UniqueEntity doesn't work

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

@UniqueEntity doesn't work for me. In controller I use $form->isValid() and form passes, but it shouldn't. Instead my own defined message, I got MySQL error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'media30' for key 'UNIQ_115E494BF47645AE'

I have following forms:

```
    class BIPType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('url');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Bip',
        );
    }
}
```

and next, overwritten FOSUser UserType form for registration which include BIPType:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $biptype = new BIPType();
        $builder
            ->add('bip', $biptype, array(
            'data_class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Bip'))
            ->add('nazwisko')
            ->add('imie')
            ;
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';
        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

and BIP entity

```
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="url", message="URL is already in use")
 * @ORM\Table(name="bips")
 */
class Bip
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", unique=true)
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = "3",
     *      max = "25",
     *      minMessage = "Nazwa BIPu musi mieć conajmniej 3 znaki.",
     *      maxMessage = "Nazwa BIPu może mieć conajwyżej 25 znaki."
     *)
     */
    protected $name;


    /**
     * @Assert\Image(
     *     minWidth = 80,
     *     maxWidth = 200,
     *     minHeight = 80,
     *     maxHeight = 200
     * )
     */
    protected $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    private $temp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $path;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean", nullable=false)
     */
    private $public;
```

Comment: Can be a validation group problem? Are the others constraints working (like the @Assert\Length on $name)?

Comment: yeah, other constraints working fine like @Assert\Length on $name...

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the form with the `fos_user.registration.form.factory` service of `FOSUserBundle`, then, by default, the `Registration` validation group is used when validating the form. Add the validation group named `Registration` to your name property.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="bips")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="url", message="URL is already in use", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 */
class Bip
{
```

Then add

```
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => array('Registration'),
    ));
}
```

to your `BIPType` class.

Comment: how are you creating the form?

Comment: it's FOSUser overwritten registration controller:

        $form = $formFactory->createForm();
        $form->setData($user);

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
         [......]

Comment: then the "groups" is required. I've changed my answer, edit your code, then clear the cache

Comment: Thank you. In my case, I need to add the groups.

Answer (score 0):

That`s because

```
@ORM\Column(name="url", type="string", unique=true)
```

is definition of database column, but not validation rule
and that`s why you get error while inserting data into DB, but not when passing $form->isValid() method

hope, this would help you

[Unique Constraints in Doctrine 2, Symfony 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545561/unique-constraints-in-doctrine-2-symfony-2)

Comment: so... how I can do this?

Comment: try go throw this link, or you may create you own additional validation, like that   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $email = $em->getRepository('Bundle:TableName')->findByEmail($enteredEmail); if ($email){return false;}

Comment: ok, thanks... but why this doesn't work? 
* @UniqueEntity(fields="url", message="URL is already in use")

Comment: Did you added this field before entity or before protected $url? Is there any error in dev console? I need more info.

Comment: I added this field before entity, first post contains code sample.
No, only error in dev log is

Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\UniqueConstraintViolationException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO bips (url, name, path, public) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params [......]

Comment: Let's think. If we want to validate data we can add @Assert annotation and validate by regexp or by data type. But do we have any another way to validate on unique option, when we should not touch DB? Any way we should take current value and match to all email`s in DB. So here is the answer - we should only send request to DB to get understanding is there exist such field or not.