# FOSUserBundle Unique Entity constraints

Tags: forms, symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle

I want to set up a unique constraint on the fields "username" and "email" but it doesn't work :

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="acteurs")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\ActeurRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet email existe déjà.")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Ce login existe déjà.")
 */
abstract class Acteur extends BaseUser { ... }
```

The form is validated by symfony and i get database error :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicata du champ 'test@gmail.com' pour la clef 'UNIQ_B85835ACA0D96FBF'
```

What is wrong ?

Comment: Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545561/unique-constraints-in-doctrine-2-symfony-2#12643186

Comment: No it is not for multiple column.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is a bug in Symfony's Validation Component concerning `UniqueEntity` using with inherited classes. It's already reported in 2012: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/4087

I've never tried it, but you can [workaround it](http://jayroman.com/blog/symfony2-quirks-with-doctrine-inheritance-and-unique-constraints) using the `repositoryMethod`-option.

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="acteurs")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserBundle\Repository\ActeurRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet email existe déjà.", repositoryMethod="findByUniqueEmail")
 * @UniqueEntity(fields="username", message="Ce login existe déjà.", repositoryMethod="findByUniqueUsername)
 */
abstract class Acteur extends BaseUser { ... }
```

And add this to your `ActeurRepository`:

```
class ActeurRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findByUniqueEmail(array $criteria)
    {
        return $this->findBy($criteria);
    }

    public function findByUniqueUsername(array $criteria)
    {
        return $this->findBy($criteria);
    }
}
```