# Sonata admin – blank page on production when ModelManagerException is thrown

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

I have defined unique constraint on one property of my entity.

```
/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, unique=true)
 */
protected $customID;
```

In Sonata admin, when new object is created with same ID, blank page on production is shown (in dev production, I can see that ModelManagerException is thrown, which is expected result).
How can I display an error on production?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html for that field and it will show validation error before saving so no exception will be thrown.

Example:

```
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @UniqueEntity("customID")
 */
class YourEntity {}
```

Comment: do you at least get validation error on dev? @kmaci

Comment: No, I can see only screen with exception.

Comment: then you did not connect it well, it should throw validation error in the sonata. @kmaci

Comment: @kmaci I added example

Comment: Thanks, the problem caused by UniqueEntity using with inherited classes (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39773960/fosuserbundle-unique-entity-constraints). I'm sorry, I did not mention that I use inherited entity. @kunicmarko20

Comment: ah, that explains it. Glad you made it work now @kmaci